# mysql search multiple values that has the same column value

Tags: mysql

Eddited to more accurate problem:
 i have a table: id, supplierCode, propertyCode, specification. While doing search in products i would like to get products that specifications has a text like value1 and value2, so to get those products i would like an query sumething like this:
`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE (specification LIKE '%value1%' OR specification LIKE '%value2%') AND (those 2 got rows has the same supplierCode)`
Or from other side of problem: Get all supplierCode's where whatever rows with same supplierCode has in the specification columns LIKE '%value1%' AND LIKE '%value2%'
Example:
id supplierCode propertyCode, specification
1  001234 11 i7-blabla
2  001234 13 15.3"
3  004321 15 i7-9761
4  004321 16 15.4"
5  003214 14 i7-15.3"

And if i'm searching for 'i7' and '15.3"' i could get 001234 and 003214 becouse they has i7 and 15.3" in their specifications

Comment: try googling for `LIKE` operator

Comment: you only need the `%` when you are using `LIKE`, not when you are using `=`. An `IN` statement would already be a better choice then using the `OR` operator

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IN clause--definitely research thi problem a bit more, you would've definitely found a solution somewhere in the web.

```
    SELECT * FROM tbl 
    WHERE specification IN ('value1', 'value2')
      AND propertyCode = 'SOME_VALUE'
```

Comment: ups, srry, i meant 'LIKE' not '='

Answer (score 0):

use `LIKE` instead of `= sign`

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE (
       specification LIKE CONCAT('%', value1, '%') OR 
       specification LIKE CONCAT('%', value2, '%') 
      ) AND 
      propertyCode = valueHere
```

but if you are sure with the specification values use `IN` instead of `OR` (actually they are the same)

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE  specification IN ('value1','value2') AND 
       propertyCode = valueHere
```

Comment: his problem is "AND (has the same propertyCode)"

Answer (score 0):

you can use **like** keyword

[pattern matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl 
 WHERE (specification='%value1%' OR specification='%value2%') 
 group by propertyCode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$find = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE (`specification` LIKE '%$value1%' OR `specification` LIKE '%$value2%') AND `propertyCode`='$propertycode'")or die(mysql_error());
$display = mysql_fetch_array($find);
```

Bare in mind you will need to change the PHP variables as you have not included any I have to presume you are looking for something like the above.

Also if you are looking to create a list then you will need to use a while statement on your fetch.